# How to generate a randomly-positioned leaf quads with a geometry shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph, geometry-shader

Does anyone have any idea how to implement a shader that manages to make this effect in Unity?

[image]

I found a [post](https://andrewgotow.com/2016/11/30/messing-with-shaders-realtime-procedural-geometry/) that explains, but I'm still learning shaders so I didn't really understood how to go around and implement it.

From my understanding we go about creating a noise texture to wrap the object, and the areas where we find white pixels a leaf quad should be generated. My problem is with generating geometry via shaders on those pixels.

Comment: Can you walk us through what parts of that post you understand, and what's the first part you're struggling with, so we know what to focus on in our answers?

Comment: Sure, from what I understood we generate some Perlin Noise wrapping the object.  Where the texture is white a mesh should be generated. I have no clue how to generate the quad for the leaf via shader.